# Slide-to-unlock style button for android

Tags: android, button, slider, drag

As the title suggests, I would like to create a button that looks like iOS' slide-to-unlock button. Right now the best solution I've found was [using a customized SeekBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910226/how-to-make-slide-to-unlock-button-in-android).

Is there a better way? Is it possible to drag an ActionBar action button? I guess not but just to make sure.

Thanks!