# How can I create a click-drag-to-edge button?

Tags: android

I've been messing around with android for about two weeks and need to make an application where you essentially click-and-drag-to-edge a view to make it like sliding button. I'm not sure the term, so probably there is an answer out there that I couldn't find.

What I've come up on my own is the following:

```
public class MyButton extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

    float defaultX;
    int defaultWidth;
    public MyButton(Context context, int width) {
        super(context);
        defaultX = getX();
        defaultWidth = width;
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                setX(X);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                setX(defaultX);
                break;
        }

        // Check if view is past width of screen
        if (getX()+getWidth() > defaultWidth) {
            callOnClick();
            setX(defaultX);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

It basically works except for when click is called, it seems to get called multiple times. That screws up when on my next activity after I call `finish()`, the screen pops back up again because it thinks click is being called over and over - usually about 4 or 5 times. I think this is due to a queue of messages of the drag event being stored for the activity.

Is there a better or 'normal' way of implementing this? The closest thing I can think of similar to what I'm trying to make is like the slide-to-unlock button on the iPhone.

Comment: You could probably modify a seekbar to suit your needs http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/seek-bars.html

Comment: Agree with @Daves. Check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910226/how-to-make-slide-to-unlock-button-in-android