# Horizontal Seletor

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create horizontal selector like in Uber android app (Please check screen shot). But that selector list must be dynamic means (Array[1,2,3,4...]). Please check screen shot: [image: Horizontal selector- Uber app.]

I trid a lot but nothing worked with grate UI like this, I have trid also this link: [check link](https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar). Its worked but bad UI because its uses paint to create things. Please help me to achieve same thing. I am trying it for payment selection option based on region. So its must be dynamic.

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use android ui widget seekbar for this purpose and then customize it.

Also you can refer the following example

[Seekbar](https://github.com/ademar111190/android-phased-seek-bar)

Comment: Also this answer of SO was very useful to me [seekbar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22410875)